# Removing zeros from a list of equations

Tags: list-manipulation

I am setting up a matrix system of differential equations that need to be solved. Some equations are redundant, and I have removed them using `UpperTriangularize[]`:

```
eqs = {{a[t]==0, b[t]==t},{b[t]==t,d[t]==t}};
eqs = UpperTriangularize[eqs];
(* {{a[t]==t, b[t]==t},{0,d[t]==t}} *)
```

I need to come up with a clever way to remove the zero elements from this list of lists (flattening it is an option). I have tried using `DeleteCases[eqs,0,Inifity]` and a solution based on `Select[]`, but neither seemed to give the desired result.

Comment: How about `Union@Flatten@eqs`? Also, how do you generate `eqs`? (Or in other words, why do you have the duplicate equations anyway?)

Comment: `DeleteCases[Flatten@eqs,0]`?

Comment: Ahh, I should point out, that I meant not to do use the `UpperTriangularize`...

Comment: @mmeent I've tried this, but some equations are of the form `a[t]==0` and somehow this seems to throw `DeleteCases` off. What seems to work for me now is to use `Table[Diagonal[eqs,k], {k,0,Length@eqs}]`.

Comment: @Julius I don't understand  `DeleteCases[Flatten@eqs,0]` does not touch equations of the form `a[t]==0`. It will only touch entries in the flatten list that are an exact match to the pattern `0`.  Alternatively, `DeleteCases[eqs, 0, {2}]` gives the same output as your `Table` expression.

Comment: @mmeent You're absolutely right! I hadn't tried with Flatten inside of `DeleteCases[]`. Any idea why this gives a different output than `DelteCases[eqn,0,Infinity]`?

Comment: By specifying `Infinity` as the level specification you are telling `DeleteCases` to delete expressions matching `0` at any level of `eqn`. This ignore `heads` so it will simply delete any `0` anywhere in the `eqn`

Comment: Why not `DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[eqs]]`? Do you need the ragged array structure for something?

Comment: @Julius: Did you receive an answer to your question above? I have the same problem as the one you had. A list of equations, some of which are equal to zero, and I just want to remove them from the list.